# Add class to a result data on a block

Tags: views

I want to initialize a block of an imported table of data first. Then I want to show the result on a the same block with a different class.
I created 3 exposed filter and it shows me the results.
I just want to hide them using CSS.
Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: I find the solution but I will explain. I had a bloc view that has a 3 inputs of exposed filter, when user tape word the bloc show the result only. first, the bloc show all data and I want to hide them. so I used required input as Exposed form style :)

Comment: Glad you got it working :)